# Theorem From Conway's Complex Analysis Book

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Here is a theorem from Conway's Complex Analysis Book:

> **5.4 Cauchy’s Integral Formula (First Version)**
>   Let $G$ be an open subset of the plane and $f \colon G \to \mathbb{C}$ an analytic function.
>   If $\gamma$ is a closed rectifiable curve in $G$ such that $n(\gamma;w) = 0$ for all $w \in \mathbb{C} - G$, then for $a \in G - \{\gamma\}$
>   $$
>   n(\gamma;a) f(a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(g)}{z-a} \,\mathrm{d}z.
> $$
>   (Original scanned picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B673.png).)

What is the $g$ and to what set does it belong? The form of this theorem I am familiar with is this:

$$
    f(z) \operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(z)
  = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}
    \int_\gamma \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}
    \,\mathrm{d}\zeta
$$

Comment: Pretty sure it should be a $z$.

Comment: It's a printing mistake. It should be a $z$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typo. The corrected version from the second edition of *Functions of One Complex Variable I* reads
$$
    n(\gamma; a) f(a)
  = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}
    \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a} \,\mathrm{d}z \,,
$$
which is then the same as your formula.